# Galaxy A10 screen replaced with a lower resolution screen

Tags: samsung, screen

My Samsung Galaxy A10 had its screen cracked and had to send it to mobile care for the old screen to be replaced with a new one. The problem is that the old screen that came with this phone seems to be clearer than the new one because the text is fuzzy and the icons are blurry they replaced it with.

So, is it possible to replace the screen of a model with a lower quality screen?

Comment: Another possibility is that the order of the color-subpixels have changed. If the phone uses optimized sub-pixel rendering (on Windows this is known as "Clear-Type") and the order changes then the display will look blurry. Not sure if you can change subpixel rendering on Android as changing the display with a different type is nothing a manufacturer plans.

Comment: yes low quality screen replacement is possible I have heared it before. but not in Samsung mobile shop

Answer (score 0):

The pixel is what I think it's called. The Samsung Galaxy A10 features an IPS LCD display with a resolution of 720 x 1520 pixels. Nevertheless, you can replace the display screen with an OLED screen replacement, so the pixels will be the same, but the quality will be better.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like you're affiliated with the website linked here. Consider reading and following our help center for [how to not be a spammer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). As of current writing, I don't see how the linked site helps, other than looking like someone trying to sell a product from their site, which looks really spammy. The link will be keep deleted, unless you can provide more details about it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: No problem you have deleted the link. But it was an example because Galaxy A10 has LCD display but the link was OLED display. However, never mind!